# Jquery autocomplete - doesn't highlight items on hover and arrows don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I've been wrestling with Jquery's autocomplete for a couple days now. I now have it properly displaying a JSON list of dictionaries from a page (/jsontest) using this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src=/static/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>   

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/autocomplete2.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: '/jsontest',
      minchar: 2,
      delay: 500,
      select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;}
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `autocomplete.css` file looks like this:

```
#tags {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: white;
    color: #96f226;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
    height: 0 0 30px;
}
#tags:hover {
    background: white; /*#656565*/
}
#tags:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px #96f226
}
#tags:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226
}

.ui-tooltip {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    color: #96f226;
    border: 2px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 
}
.ui-autocomplete {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.ui-autocomplete.source:hover {
    background: #454545;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    color: red; /*#96f226;*/
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
}
```

I got a lot of this from [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5Dt2/), but while there the arrow keys work fine and the highlighting works, on my page neither do. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user2187738, I was able to narrow it down to the jquery file I was using. Don't know if I messed it up or what, but it worked when I changed this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=/static/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrows behaviour is regulated by the "focus" option

```
focus: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

this code DISABLES the arrow keys. Given that you don't have this code, they should work fine.

However, I notice that you are using minChar while, if you are using jQueryUI, it should be "minLength" instead!

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to minLength but that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @AlexS I used your code, change the reference to jquery and used the standard source in the autocomplete example. It works! So, I bet the problem is in the JSON itself.
http://jsfiddle.net/w5Dt2/83/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I replaced all my css and js files with the ones jfiddle was using (by "viewing frame source") and tried them one by one to figure out which one was causing the problem. Turned out to be the jquery-smoothness css file.